# Convert WebApi's Returned DateTime into Javascript's Date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, asp.net-web-api2

I have a backend service written in WebApi and front end with **AngularJS.** From backend I have returned DateTime as below

```
public async Task<DateTime> GetDateTime(Guid id)
{
    DateTime dateTime = GetDateTime();
    return dateTime;
}
```

Inside angular controller I have received response like this

```
service.getDateTime({
    id: $scope.id
},
function(data) {
    $scope.minSelectedScheduleDate = new Date(data);
    $scope.isBusy = false;
},
function(response) {
    $scope.isBusy = false;
});
```

But `minSelectedScheduleDate` become invalid date.

When I tried to see the data into console I saw something like this:

```
Resource {
    0: "2",
    1: "0",
    2: "1",
    3: "6",
    4: "-",
    5: "1",
    6: "0",
    7: "-",
    8: "2",
    9: "8",
    10: "T",
    11: "1",
    12: "1",
    13: ":",
    14: "3",
    15: "0",
    16: ":",
    17: "0",
    18: "0"
}
```

My question is, how can I receive a valid Date in Angular Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I am returning DateTime object directly.  If I return an anonymous object from my controller, then Javascript deserialize everything fine. Here is my current controller:

```
public async Task<DateTime> GetDateTime(Guid id)
{
    DateTime dateTime = GetDateTime();
    return new
    { 
        ScheduleDate = dateTime
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting back a date as a string in [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format from your web api. To convert a string to a date you need to call the [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method on date.

```
$scope.minSelectedScheduleDate = Date.parse(data);
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not working. It says `$scope.minSelectedScheduleDate` is `NaN`

Comment: @EmdadulSawon - are you `awaiting` all tasks inside of your `GetDateTime` action? Can you share the angular service code for `service.getDateTime`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you get date as response in object format of string, so try this

```
function(data) {
    var dateString="";
    for(var prop in data)
        dateString+=data[prop];
    $scope.minSelectedScheduleDate=new Date(dateString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have an Angular application that returns a revisionDate: Date property from a WebApi service.  The first thing we do to it after it loads to convert it to a javascript Date like so:

```
// convert WebApi date format to javascript format
myJsonObject.revisionDate = new Date(myJsonObject.revisionDate.toString());
```